# Postgres WHERE any(arrayPostgres) = any(arrayParameter)

Tags: postgresql

how is the following condition working? i have an postgres array and call a function with an array as paramter. As condition i want to check the following:

```
WHERE any(array[x,y]) = any(array[y,z])
```

Thus is minimum one element of the postgres array in the parameter array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [overlap operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE):

```
WHERE array[x,y] && array[y,z]
```